# Cant i ADD another Layout which is other than default Layout in MVC4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Working On MVC4 architecture. I have a default layout i.e _Layout and models and view associated with it. It's Working fine.
Now Due to Some Requirement, after i Click on specific link i need it to redirect it a Whole different Layout and there i will associate models and view according to my Need.
But How to add a new layout and also keep the existing default layout in place.

For ex :- On Index page i gave a link Nikhil</a> -->. When i click this i have to go to a seperate layout and view.
Please Help in simplest and descriptive way possible because i am new to MVC4.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create multiple layout for different views if you want. In my case I have AdminLayout and UserLayout in my Shared folder. Just replace Layout variable.

Ex.

```
// For Admin Pages
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

//For User Pages
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/UserLayout.cshtml";
}
```

By the way I use razor view engine here.

Answer (score 0):

For Navigation you can create an `ActionLink` using **`HTML Heplers`** on your index page Like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Controller","Action")
```

Now when you click on this link , the action specified of the controller will be accessed and in the action you can return the desired view, which has the different layout like :

```
public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View("Desired View Name");
    }
```